# Заменить скрин на странице справки "Почему система просит меня подождать день или более перед тем, как задавать следующий вопрос?"

Tags: дефект, предложение, статус-завершено, локализация, справка

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking-rate-limited

Например, на этот:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сначала бы [регистры](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323315/339911) поправить.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ поправил :D

Comment: фейковая картинка ;)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ только тсс, никому не говорите (¬‿¬ )